Delphi select SQL to find & in rows
I am running a query to find the rows containing the character "&"
and using dbgrid to show the result.
I have tried to write query as it works in SQL Server or MYSQL
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE NAME LIKE ''%&%''';  
FDQuery1.Open();

Instead of getting the result containing the character "&" in NAME column, it's selecting all the rows where NAME column is not blank
Other queries are working when I am finding "$" in place of "&" - like this:
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE NAME LIKE ''%$%''';   

This query selecting the rows containing the $ character
It's only selecting all not null rows when I am using this condition: %&%.

Delphi is not a database engine, and does not run your query. FireDAC passes your query to the RDBMS that you're using, and that database engine executes the query.  You need to add a tag for the database engine you're using (Access, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.), because it is what is running the SQL.

@KenWhite FireDAC by default does not pass the query unmolested if it contains  any of the special characters it uses to support a query preprocessing/macro capability. Ref: Special Character Processing

@Brian: That doesn't change the fact that Delphi does not execute the query. The DBMS does that, not the development language, and knowing which DBMS is being used is still necessary.

FireDAC has a query preprocessing / macro capability to allow an extra layer of modification of queries. Some of the functionality uses the & symbol which means either extra care needs to be taken when writing queries or disabling macros. It can be turned off at the connection or query level.
  FDConnection1.ResourceOptions.MacroExpand := false;
  FDQuery1.ResourceOptions.MacroExpand := false;


Substitution Variables
‘&’ symbol and is followed by the macro variable name. For example:
SELECT * FROM &TabName
The symbols have the following meaning:
‘!’--“string” substitution mode. The macro value will be substituted
“as is”, directly into the command text without any transformation.
‘&’-–“SQL” substitution mode. The macro value will be substituted
depending on the macro data type, using target DBMS syntax rules. To
use the macros, use the following code snippet:
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM &TabName';
FDQuery1.MacroByName('TabName').AsRaw := 'Orders';
FDQuery1.Open;

The macros are processed when ResourceOptions.MacroCreate and MacroExpand
are set to True.

Ref: Preprocessing Command Text (FireDAC)
